# no GUI after upgrading to debian 10.5 (nvidia)

Tags: debian, nvidia, dist-upgrade

So I upgraded to debian 10.5 in this morning (dist-upgrade), but after that I was not able to get into GUI, as I'm having only a blinking cursor. My video card is a Nvidia gtx 1080 ti. I'm currently using the nvidia-driver from buster repository.
Luckily I had a backup since few days ago, so I restored and now it's working, but i cannot upgrade again until you guys, enlight me with an advice. Thanks!

This is the working (but deprecated) kernel:

```
Linux jupiter 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This one is the newer, updated kernel, however it's generating issues as I described above and below:

```
Linux jupiter 4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is the output from `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.19.0-10-amd64 linux-headers-4.19.0-10-common
  linux-image-4.19.0-10-amd64
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ark base-files brave-browser clamav clamav-base clamav-daemon
  clamav-freshclam clamdscan dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11 firefox-esr fwupd
  fwupd-amd64-signed glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-efi-amd64
  grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common intel-microcode
  libappstream-glib8 libclamav9 libcpupower1 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-3:i386
  libegl-nvidia0 libegl-nvidia0:i386 libexif12 libexif12:i386 libexiv2-14
  libfwupd2 libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx:i386
  libgles-nvidia1 libgles-nvidia1:i386 libgles-nvidia2 libgles-nvidia2:i386
  libglx-nvidia0 libglx-nvidia0:i386 libgnutls30 libgnutls30:i386 libinput-bin
  libinput10 liblirc-client0 libmariadb3 libmariadb3:i386 libnvidia-cbl
  libnvidia-cfg1 libnvidia-eglcore libnvidia-eglcore:i386
  libnvidia-fatbinaryloader libnvidia-glcore libnvidia-glcore:i386
  libnvidia-glvkspirv libnvidia-glvkspirv:i386 libnvidia-ml1
  libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler1 libnvidia-rtcore libperl5.28 libperl5.28:i386
  libpython3.7 libpython3.7-dev libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib
  libunwind8 linux-compiler-gcc-8-x86 linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64
  linux-kbuild-4.19 linux-libc-dev lsp-plugins-jack mariadb-common
  nvidia-alternative nvidia-driver nvidia-driver-bin nvidia-driver-libs
  nvidia-driver-libs:i386 nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 nvidia-egl-common
  nvidia-egl-icd nvidia-egl-icd:i386 nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-kernel-support
  nvidia-legacy-check nvidia-vdpau-driver nvidia-vulkan-common
  nvidia-vulkan-icd nvidia-vulkan-icd:i386 openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless perl perl-base perl-modules-5.28 python-pil
  python3-pil python3.7 python3.7-dev python3.7-minimal
  shim-helpers-amd64-signed shim-unsigned teamviewer transmission-common
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia
107 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/465 MB of archives.
After this operation, 327 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

While upgrading, I found this at the end:

```
[...]
Setting up nvidia-kernel-dkms (418.152.00-1) ...
Loading new nvidia-current-418.152.00 DKMS files...
Building for 4.19.0-9-amd64 4.19.0-10-amd64
Building initial module for 4.19.0-9-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-9-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-kernel-dkms (--configure):
 installed nvidia-kernel-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver:
 nvidia-driver depends on nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 418.152.00-1) | nvidia-kernel-418.152.00; however:
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package nvidia-kernel-418.152.00 is not installed.
  Package nvidia-kernel-dkms which provides nvidia-kernel-418.152.00 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up nvidia-driver-bin (418.152.00-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-libs:amd64 (418.152.00-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-libs:i386 (418.152.00-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386 (418.152.00-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133+deb10u1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-10-amd64
Processing triggers for shim-signed:amd64 (1.33+15+1533136590.3beb971-7) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-nvidia (1.0.0) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-mesa (1.0.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Processing triggers for update-glx (1.0.0) ...
Processing triggers for glx-alternative-nvidia (1.0.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.133+deb10u1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-10-amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-kernel-dkms
 nvidia-driver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Update**: content of `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-current-418.152.00 for kernel 4.19.0-9-amd64 (x86_64)
Sun Aug  2 17:35:42 EEST 2020
make KBUILD_OUTPUT=/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build V=1 -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source M=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build ARCH=x86_64 NV_KERNEL_SOURCES=/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source NV_KERNEL_OUTPUT=/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build NV_KERNEL_MODULES="nvidia nvidia-uvm nvidia-modeset nvidia-drm" INSTALL_MOD_DIR=kernel/drivers/video NV_SPECTRE_V2=0 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common'
make -C /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common \
-f /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/Makefile modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-amd64'
arch/x86/Makefile:151: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: /bin/gcc-8: Permission denied
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 27: /bin/gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
mkdir -p /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/.tmp_versions/*
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
make -f /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build
make[2]: execvp: gcc-8: Permission denied
NV_CONFTEST_CMD=/bin/sh /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/conftest.sh " gcc-8" " gcc-8" x86_64 /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build
NV_CONFTEST_CFLAGS=-O2 -D__KERNEL__ -DKBUILD_BASENAME="#conftest28767" -DKBUILD_MODNAME="#conftest28767" -nostdinc -isystem -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source/include/asm-x86/mach-default -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source/arch/x86/include/asm/mach-default -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build/include2 -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build/include -include /lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build/include/generated/autoconf.h -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source/include -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source/include/uapi -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source/include/xen -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build/include/generated/uapi -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source/arch/x86/include -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/source/arch/x86/include/uapi -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build/arch/x86/include/generated -I/lib/modules/4.19.0-9-amd64/build/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -m64 -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -g -pg
KBUILD_CFLAGS=-Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89  -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow  -m64        -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel              -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables         -O2     -fstack-protector-strong    -g -pg                      
LINUXINCLUDE=-I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/include -I./include -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include /usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/include/linux/kconfig.h
LDFLAGS=
(cat /dev/null;   echo kernel//var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia.ko;   echo kernel//var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia-uvm.ko;   echo kernel//var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia-modeset.ko;   echo kernel//var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia-drm.ko;) > /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/modules.order
KBUILD_LDFLAGS=-m elf_x86_64  -z max-page-size=0x200000

The C compiler ' gcc-8' does not appear to be able to
create object files.  Please make sure you have 
your Linux distribution's libc development package
installed and that ' gcc-8' is a valid C compiler
name.

*** Failed CC sanity check. Bailing out! ***

  ln -sf /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia/nv-kernel-amd64.o_binary /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia/nv-kernel.o
make[3]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/Kbuild:207: cc_sanity_check] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ARCH=x86_64
  ln -sf /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel-amd64.o_binary /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/nvidia-modeset/nv-modeset-kernel.o

Compiler version check failed:

The major and minor number of the compiler used to
compile the kernel:

gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)

does not match the compiler used here:

/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/conftest.sh: 3739: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/conftest.sh: gcc-8: Permission denied

It is recommended to set the CC environment variable
to the compiler that was used to compile the kernel.

The compiler version check can be disabled by setting
the IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH environment variable to "1".
However, mixing compiler versions between the kernel
and kernel modules can result in subtle bugs that are
difficult to diagnose.

*** Failed CC version check. Bailing out! ***

make[3]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/Kbuild:207: cc_version_check] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common/Makefile:1537: _module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-amd64'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:146: sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-9-common'
make: *** [Makefile:81: modules] Error 2
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the contents of `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/make.log`, or at least the last 30 lines?

Comment: Thanks, @StephenKitt just edited my question, added the output of: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/418.152.00/build/make.log . It looks ugly :)

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue after upgrading from Debian 10 Buster (don't know exactly which dot release) to Debian 10.5 with an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070 Ti.  When I reboot, after bios POSTs and Grub menu, I select the newest kernel 4.19.0-10-amd64.  Some logs from dmesg are output to console, but then it stops outputting messages and no login prompt appears.  Have you made any progress on this issue?

Comment: Yeah, I did a kind of progress, but it's not a solution to the issue itself. I had some full-backups, so I choose one of them which allows me to successfully upgrade from that point, to the newest kernel. Basically, I had no idea what cause this mess...